# Order by multiple timestamps in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I have this table I would like to select from. Basic structure is:

- Id
- Timestamp1
- Timestamp2
- Timestamp3 (there could be more timestamps in the future)

I would like to select and order the timestamps based on which one is equal to whichever date is chosen on the front end.

For example:

```
SELECT Id FROM table WHERE DATE(Timestamp1) = 'datevariable'
OR DATE(Timestamp2) = 'datevariable' OR DATE(Timestamp3) = 'datevariable'  
ORDER BY Timestamp1 (if it == 'datevariable'), Timestamp2 (if it == 'datevariable'), etc.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If possible, I'd like to keep this in the query rather than doing it post query (although that might be what I'll have to do).

Thanks!

Comment: And what if all the columns contain such a value?

Comment: Didn't even think of that scenario. I would most likely make the latter timestamps supersede the previous. So ts3 would set the order over ts2, 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the case when multiple columns/timestamps match the WHERE condition - The following query should work:

```
SELECT Id
FROM table
WHERE DATE(Timestamp1) = 'datevariable'
   OR DATE(Timestamp2) = 'datevariable'
   OR DATE(Timestamp3) = 'datevariable'
ORDER BY 
    CASE 'datevariable'
        WHEN DATE(Timestamp1) THEN Timestamp1
        WHEN DATE(Timestamp2) THEN Timestamp2
        WHEN DATE(Timestamp3) THEN Timestamp3
    END
```

According to your comment: "I would most likely make the latter timestamps supersede the previous." - You might want to reverse the order

```
    CASE 'datevariable'
        WHEN DATE(Timestamp3) THEN Timestamp3
        WHEN DATE(Timestamp2) THEN Timestamp2
        WHEN DATE(Timestamp1) THEN Timestamp1
    END
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! This is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know you could put a case in ORDER BY. Good to know!